# Не могу получить значение переменной из класса

Tags: php, классы

$akk - ответ мускула на запрос. Ответ верный, num_rows выдает 1. При разборе в index.php, fetch_row() верно выдает значения, но когда пытаюсь получить их через геттеры, получаю Null.

Уже два часа сижу и туплю в это и не могу найти ошибку.

```
<?php

class Player
{
    private $vkid;
    private $vkname;
    private $cases;
    private $firstlogin;
    private $lastlogin;
    private $money;

    public function __conctruct($id, $akk)
    {
        $row = $akk->fetch_row();

        if($akk->num_rows < 1){
            $this->vkid = $id;
            $this->vkname = Null;
            $this->cases = Null;
            $this->firstlogin = Null;
            $this->lastlogin = Null;
            $this->money = Null;
        }else{
            $this->vkid = $id;
            $this->vkname = row[1];
            $this->cases = row[2];
            $this->firstlogin = row[3];
            $this->lastlogin = row[4];
            $this->money = row[5];
        }
    }

    public function isRegistered()
    {
        if($this->vkname == Null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
        public function getName()
    {
        return $this->vkname;
    }
```

Comment: а применение не в разных точках приложения находится? Например конструктор вызывается в одном месте, а получение имени в модальном окне. Крч, не на одной и той же странице последовательно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, почистите код. При объявлении переменных задайте им значение, чтобы потом просто не задавать его в методе construct. И второй момент, у тебя переменная $row с знаком доллара, а когда ты её используешь в подстановке, то ты куда-то теряешь знак.

Comment: У класса нет конструктора: `__conctruct` -->  `__construct`.

Answer (score 2):

Может нужно не "row[1]", а "$row[1]"?